# How to I create radio buttons dynamically assigning them values entered by user?

Tags: jquery, input, radio-button

I have just started learning **jQuery**. I was trying to  make a todo list from user inputs. I have attempted to capture the value from input field and pass on to the input type of radio.  But though, the value is passed, the created element is not displaying the user input. My code is given below

**jQuery**

```
$("#addtodo").click(function(){
    var newtodo = $("#todoinputval").val(); /*Getting input value when and                                            storing it*/

    $("#todoinputval").val(" "); /*Resetting input field*/

    var newradio = $("<input type='radio'>").val(newtodo); /*creating a variable to be appended to my desired div */

    $("#radiotodo").append(newradio); /* Appending it to my desired div*/
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="todoinputval" type="text"><br>
<button id="addtodo">Add</button>
<div id="radiotodo"></div>
```

Comment: A radio button does not contains any kind of visible text that the user will see. If you want to display some text next to the input, you have to add something like an `label`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I wanted to create a list of radio buttons, where each contains input from the user.

Comment: What do you mean with "contains the input", should the radio button have the value or? because that is already what you have

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I want the radio button to display the user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display some text next to your `radio`, i suggest that you use a `label` and bind it to the `radio` with the attribute `for`.

```
$("#addtodo").click(function() {
  var newtodo = $("#todoinputval").val();
  var inputCount = $("#radiotodo input").length;
  $("#todoinputval").val("");
  var newradio = $("<input type='radio'>").val(newtodo).attr("id","radio"+inputCount);
  var RadioLabel = $("<label>").attr("for","radio"+inputCount).text(newtodo);
  $("#radiotodo").append(newradio).append(RadioLabel); 
});
```

**Working demo**

```js
$("#addtodo").click(function() {
  var newtodo = $("#todoinputval").val();
  var inputCount = $("#radiotodo input").length;
  $("#todoinputval").val(""); /*Resetting input field*/
  var newradio = $("<input type='radio'>").val(newtodo).attr("id","radio"+inputCount);
  var RadioLabel = $("<label>").attr("for","radio"+inputCount).text(newtodo);
  $("#radiotodo").append(newradio).append(RadioLabel); /* Appending it to my desired div*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="todoinputval" type="text"><br>
<button id="addtodo">Add</button>
<div id="radiotodo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                 <!DOCTYPE html>
                 <html>
                <head>
               <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
               <script>
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#addtodo").click(function(){
                var value=$('#todoinputval').val();
                 $('#radiotodo').append('<input type="radio"  value="'+value+'">                            '+value+'<br>');
                });
           });
       </script>
      </head>
      <body>

       <input id = "todoinputval" type = "text"><br>
       <button id ="addtodo">Add</button>
       <div id= "radiotodo"></div>

     </body>
      </html>
```

please try this

Comment: You should always add an explanation to why this helps and solves the OP's problem

Comment: thanks for suggestion....I will keep this in my mind in my future answer :)